# Advanced gmail search for received emails only

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, incoming-mail

I'm using the Google gmail API to get emails from peoples gmail account. I filter for emails containing the word "CompanyName" which have a pdf as an attachment. using the following search query: `CompanyName filename:pdf`. I now want to further specify this by only getting emails that were received, instead of sent.

Does anybody know how I can filter by received emails in gmail? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify that you don't want mails coming from you, or mails having your sent label etc.

```
q = CompanyName filename:pdf AND -from:me AND -in:sent AND -is:chat AND -in:draft AND -in:trash
```

Which would result in the following request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=CompanyName+filename%3Apdf+AND+-from%3Ame+AND+-in%3Asent+AND+-is%3Achat+AND+-in%3Adraft+AND+-in%3Atrash&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be better to just add -from:me instead of looking at specific labels.